# iOS Date & Time Set Automatically gives wrong time

Tags: ios

I just met one of the weirdest bug on iOS at my lab.

One of our device (iPod Touch 5th gen, iOS 8.4.1) kept showing a wrong time, despite that the **Location Service is on** and the **Set Automatically in Date & Time is on**. The time on that device was always 5 mins late than the correct time.

That seems not to be a big deal but a bit annoying. However, one of our apps for clinic trails is time-sensitive: it always double checks whether the device has the correct time with our server; if the time is wrong, it won't be able to launch at all.

I checked online. It seems this bug has existed for **several years**! Every time after a system update, some devices will suffer from it. I tried all solutions I found, including restart the device, putting it in Airplane Mode, etc. However, none of them works for me.

Comment: Is it possible you were using the device with Xcode at a simulated location? Like running a map app debugging location set to Tokyo? When you do that, the device will think it is in that location until you restart.

Comment: I don't think that could be the reason. On one hand, we didn't use simulated locations on Xcode. On the other hand, the offset was just 5 mins. I think it should be at least 1h if the device was in a different time zone. @GlennHowes

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution I found:

I connected the device with a different network (in my case, from the Wifi at work to the Personal Hotspot on my iPhone), then restart the Set Automatically in Date & Time. BOOM, the time finally got back to accurate EST! After that, even if I reconnected the device back the the Wifi in the lab, the bug doesn't appear anymore and the time stays correct.

No idea what caused this problem, but it is definitely a bug in iOS.